# Блокируются элементы дочернего окна в Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть три окна: MainWindow, SelectPreset, Preset. Окно SelectPreset вызывается из окна MainWindow. А окно Preset вызывается из окна SelectPreset. Но я не могу понять, почему блокируются элементы окна Preset (это происходит почему-то в Debian, в других системах я этого не заметил).

Вот как работают мои файлы:

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : 
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
.
.
.
SelectPreset select_preset;
select_preset.setModal(true);
select_preset.exec();
```

selectpreset.cpp

```
SelectPreset::SelectPreset(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui_selectpreset(new Ui::SelectPreset)
{
    ui_selectpreset->setupUi(this);
}
.
.
.
Preset preset;
preset.setModal(true);
preset.exec();
```

preset.cpp

```
Preset::Preset(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui_preset(new Ui::Preset)
{
    ui_preset->setupUi(this);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Preset preset(this);
preset.setModal(true);
preset.exec();
```

Answer (score 1):

> [virtual slot]int QDialog::exec() Shows the dialog as a modal dialog,
> **blocking** until the user closes it. The function returns a DialogCode result.

Используйте show()

> Modeless dialogs are displayed using show(), which returns control to
> the caller **immediately**.

Comment: Нет, show не блокирует выполнение программы

Comment: процитированный кусок документации ровно об этом и говорит. show возвращает контроль немедленно, а exec ждет завершения выполнения

Comment: Но ведь автор вопроса говорит, что у него блокируется дочернее окно (`Preset`), а `show` /  `exec` отвечает за блокировку родительского.